# Formatting bug: long mathjax or code blocks break entire post or page

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

Long, broken MathJax expressions seem to break the formatting of all comments on a post, causing them to spill to far over to the right. In addition to making the comments hard to read, it can make the comments impossible to edit or delete, since the edit/delete buttons are pushed over past where the browser thinks the comment ends. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/781348/8173) provides an example:

[image: broken comments]

If I move my mouse over to "edit" or the "x", they disappear before I can click on them. This has been observed by at least one other user, who brought the issue to my attention.

In addition, a similar problem seems to happen with overly-long code blocks in mod messages, breaking all the messages in a conversation. Here is an [admin-only link](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/message/954#954) to an example; I'd appreciate it if the devs would check this out.

Comment: Here's a copy of the bad code from that comment: $$f(z)=-\frac{1-iz\sqrt3}{2^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{-z+i\sqrt3}}-\frac12\sqrt[3]{\frac12\l‌​eft(-1+i\sqrt3\right)}\left(1+\sqrt3\z^{2/5}right)$$ And now let me write a very long sentence bla bla blatibitly bla bluuu (and some text)

Comment: Testing with a looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong comment to make sure that comments on this post are also broken.

Comment: There. My comment should be a good testing area now.

Comment: This is related to, if not a duplicate of, [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10195), which is related to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3953).

Comment: I just noted that the comment can be removed in the mobile SE version. I'll leave it there though for debugging purposes.

Comment: Some kind of workaround, showing how to delete a comment, was posted by Willie Wong in his naswer here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think that math scaling thingie only works on rendered MathJax.

Comment: @DanielR You are correct, I did not remember that post correctly. (I thought it was the same problem as here.)

Comment: Same issue as [this report on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230161/comment-crashes-way-into-hot-questions) and [this one on meta.stats.SE](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes).  There's a client-side CSS workaround included in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Answer (score 2):

One trick to overcome this is to use the developer tools to make the MathJax span go away (e.g. "delete node" over that faulty part).

Then everything is almost fine, and you can find the `[x]` or the `[edit]` buttons once again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that should indeed let me fix this particular problem. But I'd prefer that the devs fix the underlying issue, so I'm leaving the comment up for now.

Comment: Sure thing, I agree there's a bigger problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem on my computer: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Firefox v29.