# I can't fix a comment with broken formatting

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I can't fix the formatting in this comment (or even delete it and try again):

[How to formalize $\text{span}(S)=\{c_1v_1+\cdots+c_kv_k\mid v_1,~\cdots,~v_k\in S,~c_1,~\cdots,~c_k\in F\}$ rigorously in first order language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407797/how-to-formalize-textspans-c-1v-1-cdotsc-kv-k-mid-v-1-cdots-v-k-in#comment4971166_2407797)

because the formatting error makes the buttons for managing the comment inaccessible. (They're obscured by the "Similar Questions" panel.)

Bah!

Comment: Well, one possibility is to try do delete the comment and post a new one. See: [Workaround for broken comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/workaround-for-broken-comments). Specifically, it links to [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long/2818#2818) and [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/formatting-bug-long-mathjax-or-code-blocks-break-entire-post-or-page/13604#13604).

Comment: And the other option is to ask moderators for help. See: [Reporting comments where MathJax breaks layout](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/reporting-comments-where-mathjax-breaks-layout). (Now that you posted on meta, it is quite likely that a moderator will notice your problem. Still, you can also use a flag to get moderators' attention.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks. Your tedious and user-hostile workaround enabled me to delete the comment, which will do for tonight.

Comment: And setting the Maths Scaling back to any sensible number gives rubbish results. So that was a really rubbish workaround.

Comment: I am not sure whether your last comment should indicate that you still have some kind of problem. I tried to use "Scale All Math" to change to 10% and than back to 100% - everything looks normal to me after that. If there is still some problem, perhaps you should explain more clearly what it is. (Is it that for some reason you can't now change scaling back to normal? If you think that I can help you in some way, you can [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2017/8/27).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: sorry to sound so peevish. Safari gave very strange results after I changed the scaling.  But when I quit it and restarted it, things went back to normal. Many thanks for your help and apologies for being so grouchy.

Comment: Yes, please flag format-breaking comments that are too old to edit. They should be able to fix it on your behalf.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: the problem here is **not** to do with comments that are too old to edit.